# How to convert and Formatting UTC Time to local and dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm javascrpt

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, datetime

How can i convert the date i get from DB to a certain format.?

this is what I get, `2021-03-30T17:57:53.489Z`

I want it to be in format of `dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm` in my localtime.

expected output : `30/03/2021 11:27 PM`

what I tried so far,

```
const formatDate = (date) => {
  let data = new Date(date);
  data = data.toLocaleString('rm-CH', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
  });

  return data;
};

console.log(formatDate('2021-03-30T17:57:53.489Z'))
```

on jsfiddle i get the output like `"30-03-2021 23:27"`
but on my React native app, when I try this I get output like `Tue mar 30 23:27:53 2021`.
can someone help me out here.?

PS: My Timezone is India, GMT +5.30. the date string is what I get from my DB(create_date, Postgresql)

Comment: Works fine for me - are you sure your date string is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner with fancy string manipulation (spread out to make more readable):

```js
console.log(
  new Date()
  .toISOString()
  .replace(/-/g, '/')
  .replace('T', ' ')
  .split(':')
  .slice(0, -1)
  .join(':')
  .split(' ')
  .map((a, i) => i === 0 ? a.split('/').reverse().join('/') : a)
  .join(' ')
);
```

Or you could just calculate it manually:

```js
const date = new Date(),
      pad = (num) => num.toString().length < 2 ? `${'0'.repeat(2 - num.toString().length)}${num}` : num;
console.log(
  `${pad(date.getDate())}/${pad(date.getMonth())}/${date.getFullYear()} ${pad(date.getHours())}:${pad(date.getMinutes())}`
);
```

Or take a shortcut and use a library like [Moment](https://momentjs.com).

```js
console.log(
  moment().format('DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you found this helpful, please upvote/accept this answer.

Comment: hi mate, thanks for your help, your way is working also. I was trying to avoid libraries like Mement.js, coz I have this date conversion at one place, so I don't wanna increase my app size.  also added my answer, let me know if there is something wrong with the way I'm doing it.

Comment: Fair enough, but moment is a lightweight library. There's no real reason not to use libraries in 2021 to be honest, but I'm glad one of my answers was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a way,

```js
function formatDate() {
    var d = new Date('2021-03-30T17:57:53.489Z'),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear(),
        hour = d.getHours(),
        min = d.getMinutes();
        
        var ampm = hour >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
            hour = hour % 12;
            hour = hour ? hour : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
            min = min < 10 ? '0'+min : min;
            var strTime = hour + ':' + min + ' ' + ampm;

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;
        
    return `${day}-${month}-${year} ${strTime}`
}
```

output : `30-03-2021 11:27 pm`